# Trace/breakpoint trap during reallocation

Tags: c, graph, dynamic-memory-allocation, breakpoints, realloc

I have a graph code written a year ago which does not work now (AFAIR it worked). The graph is implemented with a square matrix which is symmetric respectively to the diagonal. I have omitted a lot of code to keep it as clear as possible, and this is still enough for the error to persist.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct
{
    int **matrix;
    unsigned size;
} graph;


void init(graph *gptr, int *matrix[], unsigned size)
{
    gptr->size = size;
    gptr->matrix = malloc(gptr->size * sizeof(*gptr->matrix));
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < gptr->size; i++)
        gptr->matrix[i] = malloc(gptr->size * sizeof(**gptr->matrix));
    
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < gptr->size; i++)
        for (unsigned j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            gptr->matrix[i][j] = gptr->matrix[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
}


void add_vertex(graph *gptr, unsigned vertex)
{
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < gptr->size; i++)
        if (gptr->matrix[i][0] == vertex) return;
    
    gptr->size++;
    gptr->matrix = realloc(gptr->matrix, gptr->size * sizeof(*gptr->matrix));
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < gptr->size; i++)
        /* ERROR */
        gptr->matrix[i] = realloc(gptr->matrix[i], gptr->size * sizeof(**gptr->matrix));
    
    gptr->matrix[gptr->size - 1][0] = gptr->matrix[0][gptr->size - 1] = vertex;
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < gptr->size; i++)
        gptr->matrix[gptr->size - 1][i] = gptr->matrix[i][gptr->size - 1] = -1;
}


#define EDGES 7
#define RANDOM(min, max) min + rand() / ((RAND_MAX - 1) / (max - min))
#define MIN -1
#define MAX 9

int **getMatrix(unsigned size)
{
    int **matrix = malloc(size * sizeof(*matrix));
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = malloc((i + 1) * sizeof(**matrix));
        matrix[i][0] = i;
    }
    
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 1; j < i; j++)
            do
                matrix[i][j] = RANDOM(MIN, MAX);
            while (!matrix[i][j]);
        matrix[i][i] = rand() % 2 - 1;
    }

    return matrix;
}


int main(void)
{
    int **matrix = getMatrix(EDGES + 1);
    
    graph x;
    init(&x, matrix, EDGES + 1);

    add_vertex(&x, EDGES + 1);
}
```

At `gptr->matrix[i] = realloc(gptr->matrix[i], gptr->size * sizeof(**gptr->matrix));` the program gets paused by an exception `Trace/breakpoint trap`. I have googled for a while, and to me it's most likely there is something wrong with my reallocation, but I have no idea what's wrong. Besides, it works fine on `clang` and even on online `gcc 7.4` whereas fails to succeed on my `gcc 8.1`. Can anyone see where I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first entry to `add_vertex`, `gptr->size == 8` and `gptr->matrix` points to an array of 8 pointers to malloc'ed memory.

```
gptr->size++;
```

Now `gptr->size == 9`.

```
    gptr->matrix = realloc(gptr->matrix, gptr->size * sizeof(*gptr->matrix));
```

And now `gptr->matrix` points to an array of 9 pointers.  `gptr->matrix[0] .. gptr->matrix[7]` are the valid malloc'ed pointers from before, and `gptr->matrix[8]` contains uninitialized garbage.

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < gptr->size; i++)
    /* ERROR */
    gptr->matrix[i] = realloc(gptr->matrix[i], gptr->size * sizeof(**gptr->matrix));
```

Since `gptr->size == 9`, this iterates 9 times, and on the 9th iteration, the garbage pointer `gptr->matrix[8]` is passed to `realloc`.  Not good.

You could iterate the loop `gptr->size - 1` times instead, and initialize `gptr->matrix[gptr->size - 1] = malloc(...)` separately.  Or to be a little lazy and avoid code duplication, you could initialize `gptr->matrix[gptr->size - 1] = NULL` before this loop, keep it iterating `gptr->size` times, and rely on the handy feature that `realloc(NULL, sz)` is equivalent to `malloc(sz)`.

Comment: Exactly, I just found it a couple of minutes ago. That last element of the reallocated array of pointers has never been allocated any memory, so I must apply `malloc` for that very last element.

Comment: Btw an interesting idea to assign `NULL` to the last element of the reallocated array, should apply it for a change :)